# How can I replace some integers to strings?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I started to learning today Python. I am trying to make a Fate dice bot for Discord. I want to replace an integer with a string and I wrote:

```
zarList = [1,-1,0]

zarsonuc = random.choices(zarList, k=4)

zarsonucsayi = sum(zarsonuc)

zartanim = {-4:'Felaket', -3:'Rezalet', -2:'Kötü', -1:'Dandik', 0:'Düz', 1:'Eh', 2:'İyi', 3:'Baya İyi', 4:'Harika'}
tanimsonuc = [zartanim.get(n,n) for n in zarsonucsayi]

await ctx.send(f"{tanimsonuc} bir zar attın.{sonuc},{zarsonucsayi}")`
```

But I take this TypeError :(

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What are the variables that you are referencing like "zarsonucsayi" and "tanim"?

Comment: @AbhimanyuShekhawat oops, my fault. I fixed it. :p

Comment: Please see the edited answer after the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace an integer to a string you can just cast it to a string. For example, if you want to cast the first number of your array to a string you may say:

```
str(zarList[0])
```

Hope it helps,(just answered by what you asked on the title)

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking at your code, the error **doesn't** appear because the list elements are not a string but because you are trying to iterate over an **int** element and **not** an ***iterable*** object.
Here:

```
tanimsonuc = [tanim.get(n,n) for n in zarsonucsayi]
```

Since

```
zarsonucsayi = sum(zarsonuc)
```

returns an **int** value, and you can't iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
zarList = [str(x) for x in zarList]
```

basicly you  iterate trough the list and convert it to a string using str

Comment: Did you test your answer? This will only create a generator object `['<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1140b4dd0>']`

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate using the `range`

```
tanimsonuc = [zartanim[n] for n in range(zar_sonuc_sayi)]
```

Output:

```
['Düz', 'Eh', 'İyi', 'Baya İyi']
```

Explanation

---

- `[zartanim.get(n,n) for n in zarsonucsayi]`

  You need to iterate through `zarsonucsayi` to do that use `range(zarsonucsayi)`

  You wanted the value of the corresponding dice value, use `zartanim[n]`